# Show all the posts from a category on a single page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am brand new to php and wordpress.

I use post categories as a simple directory and would like users to see every post from a category when they click on one, as opposed to paginating the results.

In Archive.php that comes with the theme I had tried something like this:

```
    /* Get the current category and increase the number of posts shown */
    <?php 
    $category = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->slug;
    query_posts('category_name=$category&showposts=100'); 
    ?>

    <div id="content">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- /content -->
```

However, it doesn't work. Clicking on the category shows no posts found.

I'm sure there is a much  better and simpler way to go about doing this.

A secondary question would be, what would be a good way to apply this logic only to a subset of categories I have? I suppose I could make an array of categories and query that, but it seems clumsy.

Many thanks.

Comment: You don't need to do `query_posts()` on an archive page...The default query already includes the category posts.

Comment: Ok thanks, I suppose I just used it as a way to change the query to show more posts, which it does if I manually input a category name in place of $category. There must be a better way to increase the number of posts displayed (perhaps to show 'all').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it'll solve you problem, but you got a bug in your code:

```
<?php
query_posts('category_name=$category&showposts=100');
```

A variable name in single quotes doesn't do anything. Variable expansion only happens in double quote strings (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) as well):

```
<?php
query_posts("category_name=$category&showposts=100");
```

Better yet is to skip the variable expansion and do a proper concatenation:

```
<?php
query_posts('category_name=' . $category . '&showposts=100');
```

Comment: Ah great, that fixed it thanks. I was looking around for the proper syntax but I had no idea about the difference between single and double quotes in php. Clearly I lack coffee. However I was also wondering is there a way to make showposts equivalent to all posts, rather than a fixed number?